# what is the most effective modeling workflow for abstract curvy shapes?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bezier-curves, sculpting

I'm looking for effective, idealy non-destructive modeling workflows to create non-symmetrical, abstract shapes, like those ones:

[image]
[image]
[image]

(all images taken from pinterest.com)

The deal here is not to *recreate* those shapes based on the pictures. It is about how to *create* them from scratch.
I tried different methods using curves and nurbs surfaces, but all this failed. Sculpting does not work well either, because if you try to do shapes that are interlinked without intersecting their own surface, sculpting is not the way to go. Pure polygon modeling with subsurface modifier comes close, but is pretty tedious. The workflow should focus on form and proportion, not on pushing verts around.

So what would be the best way to create such curvy shapes? What is your experience? Any advise would be helpful!

Comment: Have a look at the BY-GEN add-on by Curtis Holt, it is a free add-on. https://gumroad.com/l/BY-GEN